# how to automatically breakpoint when Django project fails in Docker environment

Tags: pdb

I have a Django project running in Docker environment, but it keeps on restarting due to some errors, which does not give me an opportunity to `docker attach <container id>` to further debug using PDB.
Is it possible to automatically pause the program at failure point and set breakpoint for further debug?
If python PDB is not capable to doing so, any other tools can do ?

Answer (score 1):

On the deployment side, logging could help.

Comment: are you referring to `docker logs <container id>`? I used it already, but I still need to use PDB to further troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put a `sleep 360000` as docker compose command and then:

```
docker exec -ti yourcontainer python ./manage.py runserver
```

When encounter a `breakpoint()` in your code this will be an interactive session.